# Local Coordinate to Geocentric

Tags: c++, vector

I've spent more than a week trying to research a solution for this and so far nothing.

Given an identity matrix as our starting position and orientation.  Then using geotrans and the known lat, long, and height of the starting position I get an x,y,z geocentric coordinate. A normalized vector from the origin of (0,0,0) gives both the up and translation for the matrix.  However, I need the forward and right so that I can pass a distance in meters from the origin into the transformation matrix and get a roughly accurate GCC.  Do I have all of the inputs I need to calculate the right and forward?

Inputs
Origin: 0, 0, 0
Global: -1645380, -4885138, 3752889
Up (Normalized): Global - Origin

Desired Outputs
Right: ? ? ?
Forward: ? ? ?

Comment: Maybe you can find people with more experience on coordinate systems here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you Mihai.  I did just that.

Comment: Three different answers can be found here...
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30448/local-coordinate-to-geocentric

Comment: Well, you should either post that as an answer or ask some moderator to close this question if you've solved it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer and two others can also be found here.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30448/local-coordinate-to-geocentric

Given a single input of the geodetic coordinate (GDC)

The first two steps have a lot done "in the background" by geotrans which is available for at least C/C++ and Java.  It accounts for the ellipsoidal nature of the earth and can do a number of conversions from one coordinate system to another.
1) Convert GDC to a Geocentric coordinate (GCC) = vector3 Origin
2) Get the GCC for a point 100m above the origin = vector3 AboveOrigin

The "up" component of the matrix is really easy and is just a vector from the point above the origin to the origin.  While I was implementing this I thought it was backwards and should be AboveOrigin - Origin but for reasons I don't understand it is as described.
3) vector3 Up = Origin - AboveOrigin
4) Normalize Up

You need a vector that is perpendicular to both your true forward or north vector and your true right.  The cross product of your true up and straight up positive Z, which is through the axis in GCC for geotrans, will give you a temp right vector.
5) vector3 temp = Up crossed with vector3 (0,0,1)
6) Normalize temp

This is your final forward or north vector
7) vector3 forward = Up cross temp
8) Normalize forward

Now recalculate the right or east vector
8) vector3 right = Up cross temp
9) Normalize right
10) Initialize your 4x4 matrix with forward, right, up, and origin

For example:
On our map we have tags that describe the top, bottom, left, and right edges of the map in decimal degrees.  From there we get the center and point above the center.

Center - (-1645379.875, -4885137.5, 3752889)
Above  - (-1645406, -4885214, 3752948)

With just those two points you can follow the steps and get a matrix the can be applied to a coordinate in local space and get back a reasonably accurate point in GCC.

To test this I found 9 points across the map through geotrans, the center of the map, the four corners, and the four points along the middle of each edge.  Ignoring the curvature of the earth and knowing that this is a small map I just took the average distance from the center of the map in GCC to each of the four edges. I then used that X/Y distance to generate 9 local coordinates to pass through the matrix and compare to the point found through geotrans.  In testing the distance of the transformed point against the geotrans point the worst result was for the top middle and top right with 57.3cm of inaccuracy with the left middle being 0 or near 0.